# Android Studio - Custom Toast Not Showing

Tags: android

I watched many videos and tried them all one by one. But I didn't get any positive results. I'm not getting an error. The message is not displayed. I could not identify where the problem was. I request help on the subject.

I also share the code blocks and XML designs I have used with you. I can't find where I went wrong.

Thanks.

Custom Toast Class:

```
public class CustomToast {
Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
View view;
View singleToast_color;

public CustomToast(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
}


public void Information(String message) {
    try {
        //  GetLayout
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.single_toast, (ViewGroup) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.singleToast_root));
        //  Initialize
        singleToast_color = view.findViewById(R.id.singleToast_color);
        ImageView singleToast_iv = view.findViewById(R.id.singleToast_iv);
        TextView singleToast_lbl_message = view.findViewById(R.id.singleToast_lbl_message);
        //  SetColor And Value
        singleToast_color.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.toastInformation));
        singleToast_iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_information);
        //  Set Value
        singleToast_lbl_message.setText(message);

        //  Create Toast
        Toast toast = new Toast(context);
        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setView(view);
        toast.show();

    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Single Toast Layout:

[Show XML Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKW3y.png)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/singleToast_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/singleToast_color"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:background="#007CC8" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.9"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/singleToast_iv"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_information"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5"
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/singleToast_lbl_message"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/unisans_regular"
                    android:gravity="center|start"
                    android:text="Bilgi Mesajı Deneme"
                    android:textAlignment="textStart"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/singleToast_iv"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Usage:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (binding == null) {
        binding = FragmentCoinsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        init();
        objectListener();
        getCoinInformationList();
        CustomToast customToast = new CustomToast(binding.getRoot().getContext());
        customToast.Information("Hi There !");
    }
    return binding.getRoot();
}
```

Logcat:

```
2021-05-14 20:01:23.352 511-2086/system_process W/NotificationService: Toast already killed. pkg=com.xxx.yyy token=android.os.BinderProxy@7f5c8ec
2021-05-14 20:02:41.352 511-2831/system_process W/NotificationService: Toast already killed. pkg=com.xxx.yyy token=android.os.BinderProxy@e0d6177
2021-05-14 20:02:43.340 511-652/system_process W/NotificationService: Toast already killed. pkg=com.xxx.yyy token=android.os.BinderProxy@f1a0981
2021-05-14 20:07:13.873 511-4668/system_process W/NotificationService: Toast already killed. pkg=com.xxx.yyy token=android.os.BinderProxy@a02aac5
2021-05-14 20:08:13.844 511-2086/system_process W/NotificationService: Toast already killed. pkg=com.xxx.yyy token=android.os.BinderProxy@d2a310c
2021-05-14 20:08:32.580 511-1805/system_process W/NotificationService: Toast already killed. pkg=com.xxx.yyy token=android.os.BinderProxy@267d652
```

Comment: you tries to access Toast on wrong place. Make it after view is initialized.

Comment: I tried it in onViewCreated. Unfortunately it didn't happen.

Comment: try instead of `LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.single_toast, (ViewGroup) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.singleToast_root));` this one: `LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.single_toast, (ViewGroup) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.singleToast_root), false);`

Comment: Sorry the same. I opened a new project and tried it. It did not succeed there either. I thought maybe a plugin I was using was blocking it. But the problem seems to be related to the code.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
CustomToast customToast = new CustomToast(binding.getRoot().getContext());
```

with

```
CustomToast customToast = new CustomToast(getActivity());
```

Comment: I tried and toast is not showing and logcat gives the same warning. :/

Answer (score 0):

in `app/build.gradle` enable `viewBinding`

```
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding = true
}
```

and update your code

```
public class CustomToast {
    Context context;

    public CustomToast(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void information(String message) {
        try {
            //  GetLayout
            SingleToastBinding binding = SingleToastBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context));

            //  SetColor And Value
            binding.singleToastColor.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.toastInformation));
            binding.singleToastIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_information);
            //  Set Value
            binding.singleToastLblMessage.setText(message);

            //  Create Toast
            Toast toast = new Toast(context);
            toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setView(binding.getRoot());
            toast.show();

        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: viewBinding is already active. I checked anyway. There is no problem.

I tried again with the class you edited. The result is the same. I added single_toast.xml codes to the topic. :(

Comment: @HakanAKKAYA, `CardView` and `ConstraintLayout` with `width` of `0dp` where Toast has no parent cannot work. Change width of `singleToast_color` to `wrap_content` and you will see the Toast.

Comment: Thanks for help ! It's working for me :) i changed for LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp" with android:layout_width="match_parent" . After working.